# I get 404, when trying to open swagger-ui.html

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-security, swagger

I haven't Spring Boot, only Spring MVC and Security.
My config:

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableWebMvc
@EnableSwagger2
@PropertySource("classpath:access.properties")
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.company.service", "com.company.dao", "com.company.controller"})

public class SpringConfig extends WebMvcConfigurationSupport {

@Value("${url}")
private String URL;
@Value("${user}")
private String USER;
@Value("${password}")
private String PASSWORD;

@Bean
public Docket api() {
    return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
            .select()
            .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.any())
            .paths(PathSelectors.any())
            .build();
}

@Override
public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
    registry.addResourceHandler( "swagger-ui.html" )
            .addResourceLocations( "classpath:/META-INF/resources/" );
    registry.addResourceHandler( "/webjars/**" )
            .addResourceLocations( "classpath:/META-INF/resources/webjars/" );
}

........
```

`pom.xml`

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
        <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
        <version>2.9.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
        <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
        <version>2.9.2</version>
    </dependency>
```

On `http://localhost:8080/api/v2/api-docs` i get enormous JSON, but whe trying to get ui on `http://localhost:8080/api/swagger-ui.html` i get tomcat 404 not found

`Tomcat Log`

```
0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 - - [30/Jun/2020:11:50:09 +0300] "GET /api/v2/api-docs HTTP/1.1" 200 20832
0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 - - [30/Jun/2020:11:51:51 +0300] "GET /api/swagger-ui.html HTTP/1.1" 404 702
0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 - - [30/Jun/2020:11:51:54 +0300] "GET /api/swagger-ui.html HTTP/1.1" 404 702
```

Many articles talk about possible solutions to the problem using the Spring Boot or adding annotation `@EnableSwagger2`, but it's useless in my case.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
@Override
public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
    registry.addResourceHandler( "api/swagger-ui.html" )
            .addResourceLocations( "classpath:/META-INF/resources/" );
}
```

Or remove `/api/` when you want to access to your docs

Comment: ```/api/``` is root url to my app
and sorry but that didn't help

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to add the package where your controller is so it will be scanned by swagger :  .`apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.basePackage("your package"))`

Here's an example

```
@Configuration
@EnableSwagger2
public class SwaggerConfiguration {

    @Bean
     public Docket getDocketInstance() {
         return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2) 
                 .apiInfo(new ApiInfoBuilder()
                            .title("Spring Boot project")
                            .description("Spring Boot bootstrap project")
                            .version("0.1")
                            .license("Unlicense")
                            .build())
                  .select()  
                  .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.basePackage("your package"))             
                  .paths(PathSelectors.any())                          
                  .build();  
     }
```

Comment: sorry but that also didn't help
what are the differences from ```RequestHandlerSelectors.any()```, is ```.any()``` will not intercept all requests?
And if there was a problem, then I would not get JSON from ```http://localhost:8080/api/v2/api-docs```

Answer (score 0):

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
    <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-ui</artifactId>
    <version>1.6.6</version>
</dependency>
```

FOR SPRING BOOT VERSION > 2.5. Use this dependency for swaggger. It worked for me

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).